# How to get lat and lon from a GeoPandas geodataframe polygon

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, geodataframe

I am looking to get the lat and lon coordinates for a number of different polygons in a geodataframe. The following code was suggested on another answer but this returns non lat and lon numbers (lon = '-888206.6310457245' lat = '4311591.57901232').

```
nc_counties['lat'] = (nc_counties.centroid.x)
nc_counties['lon'] = (nc_counties.centroid.y)
```

I have attempted to use the points_object.x as listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49635436/shapely-point-geometry-in-geopandas-df-to-lat-lon-columns). I have also tried that method on the shapely object in my geometry column.

```
nc_counties['lat'] = (nc_counties['geometry'].points_apply.x)
```

I get error "AttributeError: 'GeoSeries' object has no attribute 'points_apply'" How can I get usable lat and lon coordinates -xx.xxxxx and yy.yyyy that can be used with other programs rather than the longer odd answers of (lon = '-888206.6310457245' lat = '4311591.57901232')?

Answer (score 10):

Your data is in a projected coordinated system, and your coordinates are perfectly normal not "odd" at all.

Just [reproject](https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs.html) your geodataframe to a geographic CRS, e.g [EPSG:4326](https://epsg.io/4326)

```
nc_counties = nc_counties.to_crs(4326)
nc_counties['lon'] = nc_counties.centroid.x  
nc_counties['lat'] = nc_counties.centroid.y
```

Note lat = y and lon = x, not the other way around like you had in your code snippet.